# EventHub with NodeJS SDK - All consumers in ConsumerGroup getting the message

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-node-sdk

I hope someone can clarify this for me:

I have 2 consumers in the same ConsumerGroup, it is my understanding that they should coordinate between them, but I am having the issue that **both consumers are getting all the messages**. My code is pretty simple:

```
const connectionString =...";
const eventHubName = "my-hub-dev";
const consumerGroup = "processor"; 

async function main() {
  const consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, connectionString, eventHubName);
  const subscription = consumerClient.subscribe({
      processEvents: async (events, context) => {
        for (const event of events) {
          console.log(`Received event...`, event)
        }        
      },
    }
  );
```

If I run two instances of this consumer code and publish an event, both instances will receive the event.

So my questions are:

- Am I correct in my understanding that only 1 consumer should receive the message?
- Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EventHubConsumerClient requires a CheckpointStore that facilitates coordination between multiple clients. You can pass this to the EventHubConsumerClient constructor when you instantiate it.

The `@azure/eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob` uses Azure Storage Blob to store the metadata and required to coordinate multiple consumers using the same consumer group. It also stores checkpoint data: you can call context.updateCheckpoint with an event and if you stop and start a new receiver, it will continue from the last checkpointed event in the partition that event was associated with.

There's a full sample using the `@azure/eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob` here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob/samples/javascript/receiveEventsUsingCheckpointStore.js

Clarification: The Event Hubs service doesn't enforce a single owner for a partition when reading from a consumer group *unless* the client has specified an **ownerLevel**. The highest **ownerLevel** "wins". You can set this in the options bag you pass to *subscribe*, but if you want the CheckpointStore to handle coordination for you it's best not to set it.

Comment: Thanks @chris-radek - I thought that was only to keep the offset record, but when I explore the blob storage, I see there is also an ownsership folder.